# How to maintain session in iOS application?

Tags: ios, session

The user inputs their username and password to log in the first time.
On subsequent requests, should I just send the username/pass with every HTTPS request made to the server or can I have our server send a cookie to the app and have the app send it back using NSURLConnection or something?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, hope you get an answer.  The other solution I'm mulling is making it purely RESTful, where there is no state.  What you can do is login, then hash some key on every call to maintain security and make it so there is no state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isn't that big of a deal.  I was thinking of designing the app more from a web-based perspective, which turns out wasn't necessary.

Comment: I designed our API to use basic authentication and the app just sends the username/password in the Authorization header with each API request. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

You can securely (encrypted) store the username and password, say in `NSUserDefaults`, and have the app send the login info when requested.

Comment: I know how to store the username and password on the iPhone but I'm not quite sure what you mean about sending them again when requested.  I plan on sending them one time when the application starts and then not again until the next time they start the application.  However, I will be making additional requests for other information to populate other views in the app.  How should the server authenticate those requests?

Comment: You can send the login info with each request.

Comment: That sounds like it would work.  Would a cookie based approach also work I'm wondering?

Comment: After all, sending the username and password with each request is not really 'maintaining session'.